# How to prevent focus change on long press in Chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, focus, touch

I want focus to stay on the currently focused DOM element. I am using the usual way to prevent focus change on click on another element:

```js
button.addEventListener("mousedown", (evt)=>{evt.preventDefault();});
```

This works on normal clicks, but not on long press.

I expected it to work on long press too. Anyone knows if the behavior is a bug?

Is there any way to prevent focus change on long press?

Comment: Consider looking into [CSS pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). That may help?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks, but I do not think that will work in my case. The element that is clicked/touched is a button with actions. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3):

Listen to the [`touchstart` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event):

```
element.addEventListener("touchstart", (evt)=>{evt.preventDefault();});
```

Note that you will still need the `mousedown` event listener for non-touch devices.

Comment: Sorry, should I have mentioned I have tried that? It does not work for me. Maybe you have an example where it works?

Comment: Eh, sorry, my bad. It actually works, but the button click event is not fired. So I can't use it.